# Is there any downsampling and upsampling query based functions in mysql database?

Tags: mysql

Actually I need to query time series data from mysql database. I need to query only downsampling data not a entire data. mean every 1 min data record or every one hour data record in one year duration range(2018-01-16 16:01:00 -- 2019-01-16 16:01:00).

Actually i tried below query, I am able to downsampling and upsampling time series data by using index sequence number  like query:

```
SELECT a.signaldate
FROM mydatabase a
INNER JOIN (SELECT a.signaldate, (a.signaldate) colTIme 
                FROM mydatabase a
                GROUP BY HOUR(a.signaldate)
                ) b ON  a.signaldate = b.colTIme
```

output:

```
2022-06-14 00:59:00
2022-06-14 01:59:00
2022-06-14 02:59:00
2022-06-14 03:59:00
2022-06-14 04:28:00
2022-06-13 05:59:00
2022-06-13 06:59:00
2022-06-13 07:59:00
2022-06-13 08:59:00
2022-06-13 09:59:00
2022-06-13 10:59:00
2022-06-13 11:59:00
2022-06-13 12:59:00
2022-06-13 13:59:00
2022-06-13 14:59:00
2022-06-13 15:59:00
2022-06-13 16:59:00
2022-06-13 17:59:00
2022-06-13 18:59:00
2022-06-13 19:59:00
2022-06-13 20:59:00
2022-06-13 21:59:00
2022-06-13 22:59:00
2022-06-13 23:59:00
```

but I need like below -- each day data

```
2022-06-13 00:59:00
2022-06-13 01:59:00
2022-06-13 02:59:00
2022-06-13 03:59:00
2022-06-13 04:28:00
2022-06-13 05:59:00
2022-06-13 06:59:00
2022-06-13 07:59:00
2022-06-13 08:59:00
2022-06-13 09:59:00
2022-06-13 10:59:00
2022-06-13 11:59:00
2022-06-13 12:59:00
2022-06-13 13:59:00
2022-06-13 14:59:00
2022-06-13 15:59:00
2022-06-13 16:59:00
2022-06-13 17:59:00
2022-06-13 18:59:00
2022-06-13 19:59:00
2022-06-13 20:59:00
2022-06-13 21:59:00
2022-06-13 22:59:00
2022-06-13 23:59:00

2022-06-14 00:59:00
2022-06-14 01:59:00
2022-06-14 02:59:00
2022-06-13 03:59:00
2022-06-14 04:28:00
2022-06-14 05:59:00
2022-06-14 06:59:00
2022-06-14 07:59:00
2022-06-14 08:59:00
2022-06-14 09:59:00
2022-06-14 10:59:00
2022-06-14 11:59:00
2022-06-14 12:59:00
2022-06-14 13:59:00
2022-06-14 14:59:00
2022-06-14 15:59:00
2022-06-14 16:59:00
2022-06-14 17:59:00
2022-06-14 18:59:00
2022-06-14 19:59:00
2022-06-14 20:59:00
2022-06-14 21:59:00
2022-06-14 22:59:00
2022-06-14 23:59:00
```

Comment: What you tried to do is a hack used before MySQL 8.0 to emulate row numbers. In MySQL 8 you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to get a rank by row based on a specific order

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos : Thanks for your comment, i able downsampling data by using above query successfully. Can i get data records by using datetime instead of ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: First, it only works by chance It only works by chance and is *not* guaranteed to produce the same results each time. Second, what *is* the question ? If the query works, what isn't working?

Comment: And finally why use the quirky unsupported hack instead of the supported function that allows you to rank rows by multiple columns, groups and orders?

Comment: Thanks for your response -- i have attached query and output result in above window. There i am getting only one day data.  Can i get each day data